# Type hinting with Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse

I am developing with Zend Framework and Eclipse 3.7.1 with PDT 3.0.

I can't get the type hinting to work:

```
/* @var $var_name var_type */
```

An example of what I am trying to get: http://files.zend.com/help/previous-version/Zend-Studio-5/@var_tag_as_class_type_hint.htm

For example, in my view.phtml:

```
/* @var $pagamenti Zend_Db_Table_Rowset*/
$pagamenti-> ... gives no autocomplete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/* @var $pagamenti Zend_Db_Table_Rowset */
Don't forget a space after var_type.